# CodeIgniter Session Library stops whole script

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I was working on a project using codeigniter. But I'm facing a very serious issue when I upload this in my live server.

In controller whenever I try to use session library I got a blank page.
Say, I wrote

```
$this->session->userdata('login')  in line 56
```

This script will work fine till line number 55, but it'll give a blank page after executing line number 56.

Same will happen if I try to set session data.

This is working fine in local server in MAMP, in my live server it's not working.

Comment: have you loaded `session` library in autoload?

Comment: And also please check `$config['sess_expiration']` in config file

Comment: @Gautam3164 yes. That's why it's also working in localhost. Just not working in live server.

Comment: @Gautam3164 it's 7200 second (the default value)

Comment: Nothing in your apache log? no missing mods or anything?

Comment: try using 
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'cisession';

$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

Comment: @MikeMiller No. No error log created

Comment: Sorry further obvious question: nothing in the CI log? Do you have log level set in config.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I've found my solutions. I've to remove all the spaces from the beginning of all the php files, specially from library files.
That solves the issue